# Unable to remove added list element

Tags: dart, flutter

I've added a list element by using the following method:

```
listToAddTo.add(italianFood());
```

However, when I try removing the same element by using the method:

```
listToAddTo.remove(italianFood());
```

it does not work.

I've tried using the removeWhere method with the parameters item == italianFood(), the retainWhere method with the item != italianFood() parameters, and the removeAt method with the listToAddTo.indexOf(italianFood()) parameters, however, none  of those seem to work.

When I try printing the list, I get the following result:`

```
ListView(
   scrollDirection: vertical,
   primary: using primary controller,
   scrollPhysics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics,
   shrinkWrap: shrink-wrapping
)
```

Above methods with this result also seem to have no effect.

Necessary code is as follows:

```
  List listToAddTo = [];

 ListView italianFood() {
return ListView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  children: <Widget>[
    listEntry(
      'Fast Food Nana',
      'Mon - Sun 06:00 - 04:00',
      Container(
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.motorcycle,
            size: 30.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.navigation,
          size: 30.0,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);


  Container filterItem(String label, value, onChanged) {
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
  child: CheckboxListTile(
    value: value,
    title: Text(label),
    onChanged: onChanged,
  ),
);



bool isTrue = false;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 45.0),
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listToAddTo.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int Index) {
          return (listToAddTo[Index]);
        },
      ),
    ),
    ExpansionTile(
      title: Text('Filters'),
      children: <Widget>[
        filterItem(
          'Italian',
          isTrue,
          (bool value) {
            setState(() {
              if (isTrue == false) {
                listToAddTo.add(italianFood());
                isTrue = !isTrue;
              } else {
                listToAddTo.removeAt(listToAddTo.indexOf(italianFood()));
                isTrue = !isTrue;
              }
            });
            print(listToAddTo);
            print(italianFood());
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't remove it because are different objects.

Every time you use `italianFood()` you create a new instance of the `class`.

Create a gloval variable :

```
 ListView _myItalianFood;
```

Instantiate:

in your add method:

```
  _myItalianFood = italianFood();
  listToAddTo.add(_myItalianFood);
```

Remove:

```
 listToAddTo.remove(_myItalianFood);
```

Comment: Finally understood the issue. thank you.l

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `italianFood()` returns a new `ListView` instance on each call. So when you call `listToAddTo.add(italianFood())` you are creating a new `ListView` instance (let's call it `LV1`) and you end up with `listToAddTo` being `[LV1]`.

When you call `listToAddTo.remove(italianFood())` you are creating a new `ListView` instance (let's call it `LV2`) and asking `listToAddTo` to remove anything that is equal to `LV2`, so this ends up doing nothing since `LV2` is not in `listToAddTo`.

You could fix this by making `italianFood` a field.

`final italianFood = ListView(shrinkWrap: true, ...);`